# Failed to instantiate module angularApp due to

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this bug when I work authentification between angular js and symfony , I have bug in front end (angular js) :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.5%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Drestangular%26p1%3DTypeError%253A%2520Cannot%2520read%2520property%2520'isUndefined'%2520of%2520undefined%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.Configurer.init%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ftestauthenti%252Fnode_modules%252Frestangular%252Fdist%252Frestangular.js%253A42%253A29)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520new%2520%253Canonymous%253E%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ftestauthenti%252Fnode_modules%252Frestangular%252Fdist%252Frestangular.js%253A812%253A16)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.instantiate%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A44%253A458)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520c%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A370)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Object.provider%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A312)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520d%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A237)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A358%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A138)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.6.5%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A322%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A76%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A70%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A322%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A251)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)

and this is link error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=RestangularProvider%20%3C-%20Restangular%20%3C-%20MainCtrl

code index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"> -->
      </head>
      <body ng-app="angularApp">
        <div class="container">
        <div ng-include="'main.html" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
        <div ui-view></div>
    <!--     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
     -->    <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <!--     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     -->
        <script src="../node_modules/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

code main.html:

```
<!—Displays error or success messages-->
            <span>{{message}}</span><br><br>

            <!—Login/logout form-->
            <form ng-show="!isAuthenticated" ng-submit="submit()">
                <label>Login Form:</label><br>
                <input ng-model="user.username" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" disabled="true" />
                <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" disabled="true" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
            <div ng-show="isAuthenticated">
                <a ng-click="logout()" href="">Logout</a>
            </div>
            <div ui-view ng-show="isAuthenticated"></div>
            <br><br>

            <!—Displays contacts list-->
            <h1 ng-show="isAuthenticated">Liste des Contacts</h1>
            <article ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-show="isAuthenticated" id="{{ contact['@id'] }}" class="row marketing">
                <h2>{{ contact.nom }}</h2>
                <!—Displays contact phones list-->
                <h3 ng-repeat="moyenComm in contact.moyensComm">Tél : {{ moyenComm.numero }}</h3>
            </article><hr>

            <!—Create contact form-->
            <form name="createContactForm" ng-submit="createContact(createContactForm)" ng-show="isAuthenticated" class="row marketing">
                <h2>Création d'un nouveau contact</h2>
                <!—Displays error / success message on creating contact-->
                <div ng-show="contactSuccess" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Contact publié.</div>
                <div ng-show="contactErrorTitle" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <b>{{ contactErrorTitle }}</b><br>
                    {{ contactErrorDescription }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="newContact.nom" placeholder="Nom" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <!—Phone form-->
            <form name="createPhoneForm" ng-submit="createPhone(createPhoneForm)" ng-show="isAuthenticated" class="row marketing">
                <h2>Création d'un nouveau téléphone</h2>
                <div ng-show="phoneSuccess" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Téléphone publié.</div>
                <div ng-show="phoneErrorTitle" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <b>{{ phoneErrorTitle }}</b><br>
                    {{ phoneErrorDescription }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="newPhone.numero" placeholder="Numéro" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact">Contact</label>
                    <!—SelectBox de liste de contacts-->
                    <select ng-model="newPhone.contact" ng-options="contact['@id'] as contact.nom for contact in contacts" id="contact"></select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

code app.js:

```
'use strict';

    var app = angular
        .module('angularApp', ['restangular'])
    app.config(['RestangularProvider', function (RestangularProvider) {
            // URL ENDPOINT TO SET HERE !!!
            RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://your_vhost/api');

            RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
                id: '@id'
            });
            RestangularProvider.setSelfLinkAbsoluteUrl(false);

            RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation) {
                function populateHref(data) {
                    if (data['@id']) {
                        data.href = data['@id'].substring(1);
                    }
                }

                populateHref(data);

                if ('getList' === operation) {
                    var collectionResponse = data['hydra:member'];
                    collectionResponse.metadata = {};

                    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                        if ('hydra:member' !== key) {
                            collectionResponse.metadata[key] = value;
                        }
                    });

                    angular.forEach(collectionResponse, function (value) {
                        populateHref(value);
                    });

                    return collectionResponse;
                }

                return data;
            });
        }])
    ;
```

code main.js:

```
'use strict';

    var app = angular
        .module('angularApp')
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window, Restangular) {
            // fosuser user
            $scope.user = {username: 'johndoe', password: 'test'};

            // var to display login success or related error
            $scope.message = '';

            // In my example, we got contacts and phones
            var contactApi = Restangular.all('contacts');
            var phoneApi = Restangular.all('telephones');

            // This function is launched when page is loaded or after login
            function loadContacts() {
                // get Contacts
                contactApi.getList().then(function (contacts) {
                    $scope.contacts = contacts;
                });

                // get Phones (throught abstrat CommunicationWays alias moyensComm)
                phoneApi.getList().then(function (phone) {
                    $scope.phone = phone;
                });

                // some vars set to default values
                $scope.newContact = {};
                $scope.newPhone = {};
                $scope.contactSuccess = false;
                $scope.phoneSuccess = false;
                $scope.contactErrorTitle = false;
                $scope.contactErrorDescription = false;
                $scope.phoneErrorTitle = false;
                $scope.phoneErrorDescription = false;

                // contactForm handling
                $scope.createContact = function (form) {
                    contactApi.post($scope.newContact).then(function () {
                        // load contacts & phones when a contact is added
                        loadContacts();

                        // show success message
                        $scope.contactSuccess = true;
                        $scope.contactErrorTitle = false;
                        $scope.contactErrorDescription = false;

                        // re-init contact form
                        $scope.newContact = {};
                        form.$setPristine();

                        // manage error handling
                    }, function (response) {
                        $scope.contactSuccess = false;
                        $scope.contactErrorTitle = response.data['hydra:title'];
                        $scope.contactErrorDescription = response.data['hydra:description'];
                    });
                };

                // Exactly same thing as above, but for phones
                $scope.createPhone = function (form) {
                    phoneApi.post($scope.newPhone).then(function () {
                        loadContacts();

                        $scope.phoneSuccess = true;
                        $scope.phoneErrorTitle = false;
                        $scope.phoneErrorDescription = false;

                        $scope.newPhone = {};
                        form.$setPristine();
                    }, function (response) {
                        $scope.phoneSuccess = false;
                        $scope.phoneErrorTitle = response.data['hydra:title'];
                        $scope.phoneErrorDescription = response.data['hydra:description'];
                    });
                };
            }

            // if a token exists in sessionStorage, we are authenticated !
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                $scope.isAuthenticated = true;
                loadContacts();
            }

            // login form management
            $scope.submit = function() {
                // login check url to get token
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://your_vhost/login_check',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    data: $.param($scope.user)

                    // with success, we store token to sessionStorage
                }).success(function(data) {
                    $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
                    $scope.message = 'Successful Authentication!';
                    $scope.isAuthenticated = true;

                    // ... and we load data
                    loadContacts();

                    // with error(s), we update message
                }).error(function() {
                    $scope.message = 'Error: Invalid credentials';
                    delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
                    $scope.isAuthenticated = false;
                });
            };

            // logout management
            $scope.logout = function () {
                $scope.message = '';
                $scope.isAuthenticated = false;
                delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
            };

            // This factory intercepts every request and put token on headers
        })
        app.factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, $window) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};

                if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            response: function (response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    // if 401 unauthenticated
                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            }
        };
    // call the factory ...
    })
    app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    });
```

help me please for resolve this bug and thanks advanced

Comment: I don't see any `isUndefined` in your code?

Comment: it seems like error prompt from resctangular.js. which one (app.js or main.js) is resctangular.js?

Comment: I update my question when I add new bug when I use cdn angular 1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

I think isUndefined is a function in underscore.js, which is a dependency of Restangular:

http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined

Do you have underscore.js included in your assets?

Comment: i read and i practiced this example 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344563/symfony2-and-angular-user-authentication?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You have a reference to the lodash script in your HTML, which is more likely to be the dependency that provides isUndefined. Does lodash.js exist at that location? I've read that they renamed the monolithic file to be index.js.

Comment: now I use cdn lodash https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js but also bug :(

Comment: Sorry, there just isn't enough additional information to go off. If you can create a plunkr that replicates your problem it will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: this is link of bug in site angular https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=RestangularProvider%20%3C-%20Restangular%20%3C-%20MainCtrl

Comment: It looks as though it's not recognising Rectangular that you inject into your controller function. Strange that you don't get an error at the config stage though.

Comment: I need to see your Plunkr really (I haven't used Rectangular) but probably won't be at a computer until Monday (am on my phone now). If no one has answered by then I'll take a look.

Comment: okey men , but please help me I m blocked now :( and I update plunker when I add file restangular.js

Comment: OK, I've taken a quick look.  There were numerous problems, e.g. you had declared your Angular module twice, your scripts were ordered incorrectly, and you had declared another ng-view in main.html, which caused infinite loops of instantiating your controller.

Here is a modified plunkr, which is in a vaguely working state:
https://plnkr.co/edit/alNrJB44sJRRjY57qnpI

I would recommend that you read some tutorials about structuring AngularJS solutions, and I would look at building components, which is a more modern design pattern for AngularJS apps.

Comment: I would check out Todd Motto's style guide, which is a good one: https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

You'll notice the use of angular-ui-router in there, which I believe is far superior to ngRoute, and supports routing to components in recent versions.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router